# Ajax.BeginForm partial view replace whole page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I had some problem in my MVC application, when I use button (submit) everything is okay but if I use `onchange`, partial view opened in the same window not replaced any div, I use all methods what I see here, but nothing help, here all code (any does not work correctly).
Why its Happens?

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<string> Year = new List<string>();
        Year.Add("1");
        Year.Add("2");
        Year.Add("3");
        Year.Add("4");
        ViewBag.Years = new SelectList(Year);
        return View();
    }
 public PartialViewResult testt()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
    [HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult testTwo()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
}
```

View (I am include on my page all scripts unobtrusive ajax, microsoft ajax, jquery and many others):

```
<script src="~/Scripts/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/_references.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.intellisense.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.debug.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("testt", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "testDiv", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))

{
<div>
    <div >
       @Html.DropDownList("UnitsNames", (SelectList)ViewBag.Years, new { onchange = "$(this.form).onsubmit()" })
    </div>
    <div >
        @Html.DropDownList("Years", (SelectList)ViewBag.Years, new { onchange = "$(this.form).submit()" })
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownList("Years", (SelectList)ViewBag.Years, new { onchange = "this.form.submit()" })
    </div>
    <div>
               @Html.DropDownList("Years", (SelectList)ViewBag.Years, new { onchange = "this.form.onsubmit()" })
    </div>
</div>
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("testTwo", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "testDiv", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))

{
<div>
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownList("Years", (SelectList)ViewBag.Years, new { onchange = "$(this.form).onsubmit()" })
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownList("Years", (SelectList)ViewBag.Years, new { onchange = "$(this.form).submit()" })
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownList("Years", (SelectList)ViewBag.Years, new { onchange = "this.form.submit()" })
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownList("Years", (SelectList)ViewBag.Years, new { onchange = "this.form.onsubmit()" })
    </div>
</div>
}

<br>
<div id="testDiv">
    <h4>here i need a partial view</h4>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You import a lot of libraries double. Only use the .min OR the regular

Comment: i am know its only for testing

Comment: Having the same issue.. The "this.form.submit" seems to outright ignore everything except the action= and perform the full page post.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include

```
@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

this in your page, else it won't work. Try like this, and not with the script tag.

Answer (score 0):

In your second Ajax form,method is POST,but you've not defined any Action method with HttpPost Attribute

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("testt", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "testDiv", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
```

Add HttpPost like below

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult testt()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
```

Comment: I am add [HttpPost] but problem the same (partial view opened in window, not replace <div id="testDiv"> ). This all methods in that View does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I am using Visual Studio 2015, so I just simply updated all NuGet packages and the code started to work as intended.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I noticed script does not work if it's included in different pages.

Add Script in your _layout page

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")"></script>
```

and Remove from place where you do not need it.